# Reciprocal & dependent axis with System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting

Tags: c#, winforms, charts, axis

I'm trying to visualize data from my lab inside a C# Winforms application. For proper visualisation i need two dependent X-axis where one of them is reciprocal.

I tried to set the whole thing up whith System.Windows.Forms.DataVisualization.Charting Library. But i don't find anything regarding reciprocal dependency. I also tried to set it up with Oxyplot with a second X-axis having ticks at the same Position as on X1-axis. But i wanted separated ticks.

this is basically what i want to do

[image: https://i.imgur.com/eEb0mG1.png]

If it is not possible with the Windows.forms package, is there anyone (free) which can do this?

Comment: Have you resolved your problems?

Comment: I resolved this Problem using oxyplot (https://github.com/oxyplot/oxyplot/issues/1278)

Answer (score 0):

You can show two axis for both x- and y-values:

```
ChartArea ca = chart1.ChartAreas[0];
ca.AxisX2.Enabled = AxisEnabled.True;
```

The secondary axes will be placed opposite to the primary ones by default.

To make it show a different set of numbers, you need to accociate it to a different `Series`.

```
Series s2 = chart1.Series.Add("s2");
s2.XAxisType = AxisType.Secondary;
```

You now need to add reciprocal data to the second series' points and, if you don't want to show it make the `Color` transparent and hide from the Legend:

```
s2.IsVisibleInLegend = false;
s2.Color = Color.Transparent;
```

If you can't add suitable values you may workaround by adding `CustomLabels` to the secondary axis.